# Why is rand() not giving me a random sequence of numbers?

Tags: c++, random, seeding

I'm trying to make a Tetris game using the SDL-library. When a new shape appears I want it to be random, so therefore I've tried to make a function that takes a takes a random number between 0 to 4, which is later used to decide what shape that will appear. Here's the function so far:

```
int EventHandler::setShapeType() {

    if (m_seeded == false) {
        srand(time(NULL) * SDL_GetTicks()); //SDL_GetTicks returns the number of miliseconds since the SDL_library was initialized
        m_seeded = true;
    }

    int shapeType = (int) (((double) rand()/RAND_MAX) * 4.999);

    cout << shapeType << endl;

    return shapeType;
}
```

`m_seeded` is a method variable in `EventHandler` and is set to `false` in the constructor, so the first if-statement only runs once.

As you can see the function is not complete yet, and the printing of shapeType is solely there for debugging purposes, but so far it should atleast be able to generate a random number... Which it doesn't seem to do. In my main function I made a 10000 iteration loop in which counted how often every number between 0 to 4 was returned, and afterwards printed out the final result as percentage relative to the maximum number of iterations. Here's the result:

- Zero: 29.8
- One: 23.9
- Two: 19.2
- Three: 14.7
- Four: 12.4

Now, I thought that for 10000 iterations every number would appear around the same number of times, but they don't! With small differences, this is the result I get every time. I know that `rand()` in fact just takes numbers from a premade list, and that the "randomness" comes from what seed you use, but shoudn't I get more varied results than what I'm getting? Well, I'm lost, I'd love some help on this.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That may not the right dupe target.  The user is calling `srand` conditionally.  We just cannot tell if that condition ever happens without an [mcve].

Comment: If this code is executed near the start of your program, it seems like `SDL_GetTicks` could very easily be returning 0 every time you run the program, which means you are getting the same seed (0) every time. I don't see any reason to not just use `time(NULL)` by itself.

Comment: `<random>` is much nicer, use the stuff in there.http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: When I want a random range I normally do something like `rand() % range + 1`

Comment: Which libc implementation is this? I ran your generator against glibc and got very closely equal values for each bucket. srand shouldn't affect the distribution because the LCRNG period is much larger than your 10k test.

Comment: Something worth watching: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Try checking the value of `SDL_GetTicks()` in your debugger (or print it out) every time it is used.  That will tell you if a) you are calling `srand()` more than once or b) you are multiplying by zero.  As Benjamin said, it might be returning 0.

Comment: @matt Bad advice, that can lead to [modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/2166798).